# Tor Browser Bundle does not work on OpenBSD

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I downloaded [TBB version 4.5.3 for GNU/Linux](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux) and extracted it on OpenBSD version 5.7 (current version which is basically a daily snapshot.)

I unzipped TBB on the said OS and after I `cd` to the directory where the contents of TBB had been extracted, I typed the following command:

```
./tbb    -v
```

and many error messages appeared.

Why does the "[Download Tor](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux)" page claim that TBB is vaild for *BSD operating systems when it does not work on OpenBSD 5.7?

Comment: See http://trac.haqistan.net/blog/adventures-ports-tor-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a specific answer, there seems to be several issues, there is however a project website that's trying to change this.

https://torbsd.github.io/

> The Tor BSD Diversity Project (TDP) is an initiative seeking to extend
>   the use of the BSD Unix operating systems in the Tor public anonymity
>   network.

They have a repo for a tbb ports package:

https://github.com/torbsd/openbsd-ports

They do also state in their faq:

> “Doesn’t the Tor web site download page list a Tor Browser Bundle for
>   GNU/Linux, that also supports ‘Unix, BSD’?”
>
> "That is true, but unfortunately inaccurate. The current Tor download
>   does not work on any of the BSDs for a variety of reasons."

Comment: Thanks very much for TorBSD's faq `"That is true, but unfortunately inaccurate. The current Tor download does not work on any of the BSDs for a variety of reasons."`.