# Compile and install (?) Tor Browser Bundle using source code on OpenBSD

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I refer to my earlier post titled [Tor Browser Bundle does not work on OpenBSD](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7340/tor-browser-bundle-does-not-work-on-openbsd?noredirect=1#comment7043_7340)

As the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) available for download on Tor's official site does not work out of the box on *BSD operating systems such as OpenBSD, could someone show me the detailed steps for compiling and installing (?) TBB using the source code.

Note: I believe TBB is not meant to be installed, right?

Answer (score 1):

For the bog-standard, non-*BSD TBB source code, have a look at the links on [this](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html#feedback) page, under "How can I make my own bundle?"

Also see the accompanying "Building with Gitian" [wiki page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/BuildingWithGitian).

For the *BSD-related changes, it might be best to start by navigating through the [FAQ](https://torbsd.github.io/faq.html) of project involved in the port
(or [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/torbsd/openbsd-ports)).